# SSRS hidden parameter based on dataset returns no data suppress default message

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, hidden

I have an SSRS report that has a hidden parameter that is based on a dataset. the parameter is multivalued and is set as the default value as well. If the dataset returns no data is there a way to suppress the  message during report preview "The *parameter name* is missing a value" and continue to load report.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this but I would do something like...

Allow null values on the parameter.

Then in your report check the number of selected items in your parameter and set the hidden property of a text box (with your info/warning in) to show the textbox if something nothing is selected. Set the `Hidden` property to something like

```
=Parameters!myParameter.Count >0
```

Alternatively check the first value is not empty with something like

```
=LEN(Parameters!myParameter.Value(0)) > 0
```

Comment: The parameter is multi valued and does not allow setting it to null. the reason i am using a hidden parameter based on data set it to capture not in data. the hidden parameter returns all data and then it is compared to another data set using not in to get the missing values. Alan, You actaully helped me with this solution using hidden paramers, see SSRS Compare Two Datasets For Missing Ids. Thanks